# how to connect to web host mysql db from localhost

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to connect to my webhost MYSQL from my localhost.

I have a host (www.printcity24.com) with mysql db and I use this code to connect to mysql db :

```
<?php
    $db_path = mysqli_connect('printcity24.com', 'myuser', 'mypass', 'mydb', '3306');
    if(!$db_path) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        echo "Connected successfully";
    }

?>
```

when i call this code from printcity24.com every thing is OK and connect to mysql db successfully.

but i created a localhost by xampp on my computer and when i call this code i got this error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\Program
>   Files\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 2
>
> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\Program Files\XAMPP\htdocs\index.php on line 2 MySQL server
>   has gone away

---

I talk to my web host admin and opened 3306 port on my host and added % to Manage Access Hosts on CPanel > remote MYSQL

but i still have problem to connection.

Comment: Can you use a tool such MySQL WorkBench to connect to your remote DB?

Comment: why should i use MySQL WorkBench ? does it better than xampp? i dont know how to use it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with xamp. It's a tool to manage your MySQL databases. You can use it to check if you can remotly connect to your db

Comment: To add to what Cid said, the purpose of doing so is to rule out the possibility of an issue in your PHP code, since Workbench is known to connect properly to Mysql.

Comment: Another thing to try is explicitly adding your (public) IP address to the allowed hosts lists, rather than just %.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added my public IP but still have that problem.

Comment: i use mysql workbench to connect to my webhost. but i got error for connection and could not connect. what should i do now ?